# How to Convert response from api using graphQL to Plain Old Dart Object in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql

I am trying to convert the Json to PODO(Dart Model Class) but getting following error :

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Model Class**

```
class FormModel {
  final String id;
  final String name;

  FormModel({this.id, this.name});

  factory FormModel.fromJSON(dynamic data) {
    return FormModel(id: data["id"], name: data["name"]);
  }
}
```

**Creating object from JSON**

```
FormModel form = FormModel.fromJSON(jsonData);
```